# How to create new URL link for wordpress post type page

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type, permalinks

I want to create custom URL for custom post type page.
Recently, i was displayed my custom post as listing page with `http://example.com/?post_type=movie`.
I want to change this link to `http://example.com/movie`. So, i want to know the way to change this link in wordpress. Thanks

Comment: I don't really understand your question. Have you turned on permalinks in wordpress settings in the admin panel?

Comment: http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks

Comment: I was already turned on permalinks in wordpress settings. The last option **Custom Structure** as "/news/%post_id%" because i want to display default post as [link]http://www.example.com/news/123[/link].

Answer (score 0):

Change permalink from admin panel.
In Permalink setting select post name option-
i.e.
Post name `http://www.example.com/sample-post/`

Comment: if use **http://www.example.com/sample-post/** in custom permalinks for custom post type, it OK for **http://example.com/movie**. I also want to set **News** as default post type **http://example.com/news/123**.